# Difference between No-Interface View and Interface View in EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

What is difference between No-Interface View and Interface View in EJB?

Advantages and disadvantages of both of them.

Comment: I recommend this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729905/what-is-local-remote-and-no-interface-view-in-ejb

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK EJB 3.1 no-interface view means that the local interface or proxy is implicitly generated by the container, i.e. all public methods of the bean are exposed.

In contrast, providing an explicit interface allows you to specify which methods are actually exposed and how the interface is named.