# Error In Java EE Web App_ NetBeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

i am trying to create a simple web app using mysql db in netbeans.
but when i run the application i get the following error.
I have no idea what the error is telling. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean,Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session into class PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
```

EDIT:
STACK TRACE:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean,Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session into class PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:133)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:629)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:234)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:196)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean,Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session into class PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
... 68 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean,Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean not found]]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
... 71 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean,Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean not found]]
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
... 75 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean not found]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
... 80 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean not found
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
... 84 more
```

EJB is used managed bean.. the code is as follow:

```
package PresentationLayer;

import DataLayer.*;
import LogicLayer.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Named(value = "placesManagedBean")
@Dependent

public class PlacesManagedBean implements Serializable{
@EJB
private PlacesSessionBean placesSessionBean; 
private List<Places> places;

public PlacesManagedBean() {
}
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{places = placesSessionBean.getPlaces();}

public List<Places> getPlaces ()
        {return places;}

public void setPlaces(List<Places> places)
    {this.places = places;}    
}
```

Comment: This is an exception that occurred during EJB injection. Please post the complete stack trace and the part of code where you are performing EJB injection (look for @EJB and similar annotations).

Comment: @MiljenMikic... i have added stack trace and managed bean of the the app.

Comment: If your `PlacesSessionBean` implements some remote interface, then you should change the declaration into: `@EJB private PlacesSessionRemoteInterface placesSessionBean;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is here:

```
Remote 3.x interface =LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,
mappedName=,jndi-name=LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean,refType=Session 
into class PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean: Lookup failed for 
'java:comp/env/PresentationLayer.PlacesManagedBean/placesSessionBean'
```

and here:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 
'LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean' in 
SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
 java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} 
[Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean#LogicLayer.PlacesSessionBean not found]
```

It appears that `PlacesSessionBean` is a remote bean that cannot be located by JNDI. You have to study how to look up remote EJBs or, if a remote bean is not necessary, how to make your EJB a local bean and/or a no-interface one.

**Useful Links**:

- [Accessing Enterprise Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm#GIPJF) (from Oracle's Java EE 7 Tutorial)
- [EJB 3.1 @LocalBean vs no annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889563/ejb-3-1-localbean-vs-no-annotation)
- [What is local/remote and no-interface view in EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729905/what-is-local-remote-and-no-interface-view-in-ejb)

For better help, post the EJB interface / implementation definitions, and relevant EJB descriptors if any.