# EJB: exposes a local vs implement local business interface

Tags: ejb

The Java EE 7 Tutorial says that `no-interface` view will "exposes a local" and "Business Interfaces" will "implement local business interfaces", but the code is same. What is the difference between them? Please give me an example, I am newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that bean is implementing a `local` interface, the interface can be packaged in different module and this module can be later imported into the client application, thus hiding the implementation. On the other hand, `no-interface` view means that client would need to have dependency on the implementation which is less flexible solution.

So generally, you can safely use `no-interface` view when bean will interact only within your service (let's say some DAO helper class) and use bean with `local` interfaces it there is ever going to be used on the client side.

Nice explanation about all views is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729905/what-is-local-remote-and-no-interface-view-in-ejb).